# How to get last 3 years data by dropdownlist in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

How to get last 3 years data by dropdownlist in asp.net c# :

Code in SQL Server stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAllTransactionsTime]
    (@Time VARCHAR(100),
     @div_id INT)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SUCCESS SMALLINT,
            @FAILED SMALLINT,
            @ERROR_SEVERITY SMALLINT,
            @ERROR_STATE1 SMALLINT,
            @theErrorMsg NVARCHAR(4000),    
            @theErrorState INT

    BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION 
        IF (@Time = 'Today') 
        BEGIN
            SELECT *
            FROM [dbo].CandidatesDetail AS c
            WHERE c.is_deleted = 0  
              AND CAST(c.CreatedDate AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) 
              AND c.DeptId = @div_id
            ORDER BY CandidateId DESC
        END
        ELSE IF (@Time = 'This Year') 
        BEGIN
            SELECT *
            FROM [dbo].CandidatesDetail AS c
            WHERE c.is_deleted = 0  
              AND YEAR(c.CreatedDate) = YEAR(GETDATE()) 
              AND c.DeptId = @div_id
            ORDER BY CandidateId DESC
        END
        ELSE IF (@Time = 'Last Year') 
        BEGIN
            SELECT *
            FROM [dbo].CandidatesDetail AS c
            WHERE c.is_deleted = 0  
              AND CAST(c.CreatedDate AS DATE) >= DATEADD(YEAR, -1, CASTGETDATE() AS DATE) 
              AND c.DeptId = @div_id
            ORDER BY CandidateId DESC
        END
        ELSE IF (@Time = 'Last 2nd Year') 
        BEGIN
            SELECT *
            FROM [dbo].CandidatesDetail AS c
            WHERE c.is_deleted = 0  
              AND CAST(c.CreatedDate AS DATE) >= DATEADD(YEAR, -2, CASTGETDATE() AS DATE) 
              AND c.DeptId = @div_id
            ORDER BY CandidateId DESC
        END
        ELSE IF (@Time = 'Last 3rd Year') 
        BEGIN
            SELECT *
            FROM [dbo].CandidatesDetail AS c
            WHERE c.is_deleted = 0  
              AND CAST(c.CreatedDate AS DATE) >= DATEADD(YEAR, -3, CASTGETDATE() AS DATE) 
              AND c.DeptId = @div_id
            ORDER BY CandidateId DESC
        END

        COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH    
        SET @theErrorMsg = error_message()    
        SET @theErrorState = error_state()    

        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION    

        RAISERROR (@theErrorMsg, @ERROR_SEVERITY, @theErrorState)    
        RETURN (@FAILED)    
    END CATCH   
END
```

Backend code in C#

```
protected void Dtime_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Dtime.SelectedIndex != 0)
        {

            BindTime(Dtime.SelectedItem.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            rptCandidateDetails.DataSource = null;
            rptCandidateDetails.DataBind();
            rptCandidateDetails.Visible = false;
        }
    }


    private void BindTime(string Time)
    {
        DataSet ds = null;
        CandidateDetails objCandidateDetails = null;
        try
        {
            objCandidateDetails = new CandidateDetails();


            ds = new DataSet();

            if (Session["DeptId"] != null)
            {
                int div_id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["DeptId"].ToString());



                ds = objCandidateDetails.GetAlltransactionsTime(Time, div_id);
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    rptCandidateDetails.DataSource = ds;
                    rptCandidateDetails.DataBind();
                    rptCandidateDetails.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    rptCandidateDetails.DataSource = null;
                    rptCandidateDetails.DataBind();
                    rptCandidateDetails.Visible = false;
                }
            }
        }


        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorLog.AddErrorLog(ex.Message, ex.Source, ex.StackTrace, ex.TargetSite.ToString());
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (ds != null)
            {
                ds.Dispose();
                ds = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

front code c#

```
<asp:DropDownList CssClass="input-large chosen-select" ID="Dtime" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Dtime_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" AutoPostBack="true" InitialValue="-1">
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Today" Text="Today"></asp:ListItem>

                                    <asp:ListItem Value="This Year" Text="This Year"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Last Year" Text="Last Year"></asp:ListItem> 
                               <asp:ListItem Value="Last 2nd Year" Text="Last 2nd Year"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Last 3rd Year" Text="Last 3rd Year"></asp:ListItem> 




</asp:DropDownList>
```

Appcode

```
public DataSet GetAlltransactionsTime(string Time, int div_id)
{
     DataSet ds = null;
     try
     {
          SqlParameter[] arParams = new SqlParameter[2];
          m_objconn = new SqlConnection(m_strcon);

          arParams[0] = new SqlParameter("@Time", Time);
          arParams[1] = new SqlParameter("@div_id", div_id);
          ds = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(m_objconn, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "GetAlltransactionsTime", arParams);
          return ds;

      }

      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          throw ex;
      }
      finally
      {
          if (ds != null)
          {
              ds.Dispose();
              ds = null;
          }
      }

}
```

I have tried this but my output is not correct. help me to get my result like show value of year in dropdownlist and by selecting year, it shows data of that particular year. Need to get advance search based on year.

Thank you

Comment: _"my output is not correct"_ - please elaborate. What do you expect to see and what do you actually observe?

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of changes  that needs to be done to the code. 1st thing is for last year, last 2nd year and last 3rd year the syntax near cast was incorrect there was an opening bracket missing.

Please find  the corrected code below:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAllTransactionsTime]
    (@Time VARCHAR(100),
     @div_id INT)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @SUCCESS SMALLINT,
        @FAILED SMALLINT,
        @ERROR_SEVERITY SMALLINT,
        @ERROR_STATE1 SMALLINT,
        @theErrorMsg NVARCHAR(4000),    
        @theErrorState INT

BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION 
    IF (@Time = 'Today') 
    BEGIN
        SELECT *
        FROM [dbo].CandidatesDetail AS c
        WHERE c.is_deleted = 0  
          AND CAST(c.CreatedDate AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) 
          AND c.DeptId = @div_id
        ORDER BY CandidateId DESC
    END
    ELSE IF (@Time = 'This Year') 
    BEGIN
        SELECT *
        FROM [dbo].CandidatesDetail AS c
        WHERE c.is_deleted = 0  
          AND YEAR(c.CreatedDate) = YEAR(GETDATE()) 
          AND c.DeptId = @div_id
        ORDER BY CandidateId DESC
    END
    ELSE IF (@Time = 'Last Year') 
    BEGIN
        SELECT *
        FROM [dbo].CandidatesDetail AS c
        WHERE c.is_deleted = 0  
          AND CAST(c.CreatedDate AS DATE) >= DATEADD(YEAR, -1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
          AND c.DeptId = @div_id
        ORDER BY CandidateId DESC
    END
    ELSE IF (@Time = 'Last 2nd Year') 
    BEGIN
        SELECT *
        FROM [dbo].CandidatesDetail AS c
        WHERE c.is_deleted = 0  
          AND CAST(c.CreatedDate AS DATE) >= DATEADD(YEAR, -2, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
          AND c.DeptId = @div_id
        ORDER BY CandidateId DESC
    END
    ELSE IF (@Time = 'Last 3rd Year') 
    BEGIN
        SELECT *
        FROM [dbo].CandidatesDetail AS c
        WHERE c.is_deleted = 0  
          AND CAST(c.CreatedDate AS DATE) >= DATEADD(YEAR, -3, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
          AND c.DeptId = @div_id
        ORDER BY CandidateId DESC
    END

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH    
    SET @theErrorMsg = error_message()    
    SET @theErrorState = error_state()    

    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION    

    RAISERROR (@theErrorMsg, @ERROR_SEVERITY, @theErrorState)    
    RETURN (@FAILED)    
END CATCH   
END
```

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure GetAllTransactionsTime, Line 38
Incorrect syntax near '*'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure GetAllTransactionsTime, Line 47
Incorrect syntax near '*'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure GetAllTransactionsTime, Line 56
Incorrect syntax near '*'.   - in sql server

Comment: @NiketaSingla: I've removed those extra ** characters, I had added them to highlight  the modified code to bold. Please check the code now and let me know if it works or not.~Sridhar

Comment: the data shows in all except in today, but it should show only in this year.as created date date is in 2019